# How to store all data in JSON files instead of the database in laravel and where the path for this file

Tags: json, laravel

I started learning laravel recently and have a project in which all data should be stored in JSON files not in the database.

- Where are these files stored?
- How can I deal with them I did not find many sources?

The majority depends on the database.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is "wherever you choose to that your application can write to". Meaning you can simply do `file_put_contents('resources/some_file.json', json_encode($objectWithTheData));`.

But if you choose to store data in files you have to make a few decisions -- clear up some issues:

- Do you plan to store a lot of data? -- too much data in a single file means loading the entire file and processing it every time you need the smallest piece of data.
- Do you plan to search through that data? -- searching in a large object becomes complicated and if you have the entire data loaded into memory with many values to search it might become slow (for millions of record).
- Do you plan to keep that data spread out into multiple files or one big file? -- breaking data into pieces makes it easier to load just the piece you need, and harder to search for.
- Do you have multiple servers (for load balancing) that need access to some shared files? -- having multiple servers means that the data needs to be stored in a shared space you can't simply write it on the current server's disk because the other server(s) won't have access to it.
- Do you want to save them "off-site" meaning on a different server? Possibly multiple servers? -- needing a secure backup or making sure that updating the code doesn't affect the data.

Based on the above answers your requirements will change and the answer will change with it.

Most of the answers to the questions above are easier to address if you use a database. They are usually cheap enough and fast enough to make it a standard approach because they can solve so many of these issues and bring so many other features out of the box.

Comment: Certainly, the database is better for storing data and through your questions I have more knowledge of its features Thank you,
What drives me to use files is that it is a university project and one of the conditions is that it prevents the use of the database relying on the file system for storing data, it may be for an educational purpose or something like that.
So I am forced to use the file system instead of the database
And for the sake of the amount of data, the data will not be very large, in the end it is not a profit project

Comment: This answer most questions: University won't care about multi-server, won't care about backups and availability, won't have large amounts of data.

Comment: So my initial answer still stands: `file_put_contents('filename.json', json_encode($data))`.